# Unbiased estimators of theta

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, mean-square-error

Suppose $\hat\theta_1$ and theta $\hat\theta_2$ are both uncorrelated and unbiased estimators of $\theta$, and that $\text{var}\hat\theta_1=2\cdot \text{var}(\hat\theta_2)$.

a) Show that for any constant $c$, the weighted average theta $\hat\theta_3= c\cdot\hat\theta_1 +(1-c)\cdot\hat\theta_2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$.

b) Find the $c$ for which $\hat\theta_3$ has the smallest MSE.

c) Are there any values for $c$ $(0\le c\le 1)$ for which $\hat\theta_3$ is better (in the sense of MSE) than both $\hat\theta_1$ and $\hat\theta_2$?

Answer (score 1):

For part (a)

$\begin{align}
E(\hat{\theta}_{3})&=E(c\hat{\theta}_{1}+(1-c)\hat{\theta}_{2})\\
&=cE(\hat{\theta}_{1})+(1-c)E(\hat{\theta}_{2}) \\
&=c\theta+(1-c) \theta \\
&=c\theta+\theta-c\theta\\
&=\theta
\end{align}
$

For part(b)

$\begin{align}
Var(\hat{\theta}_{3})&= Var(c \hat{\theta}_{1}+(1-c) \hat{\theta}_{2}) \\
&= c^{2} Var(\hat{\theta}_{1}) +(1-c)^2 Var(\hat{\theta}_{2}) \\
&= 2c^2 Var(\hat{\theta}_{2}) +(1-c)^2 Var(\hat{\theta}_{2})\\
&= Var(\hat{\theta}_{2})(2c^2+(1-c)^2)\\
\end{align}
$

To find the minimum variance, we take the derivative with respect to $c$ and equate it with zero

$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dc} Var(\hat{\theta}_{3})&= 4c+2(1-c)(-1) =0 \\
&= 4c+-2+2c=0 
\end{align}
$

Therefore, $c=\frac{1}{3}$